# Display multiple data using DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a DataList and now i need to display all data(comments) from database column which is **"comment"** while displaying the rest just once.

**example:sample Datalist**

```
<DataList>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_cmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("product") %>' />
     <br/>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_cmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comment") %>' />
 <ItemTemplate>
</Datalist>
```

Here i want to display all comments for the single product.

**EDIT**:Here's the codebehind

```
   public void showdata()
{

    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from mytable", sq.con);
    SqlDataReader sd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    mydatalist.DataSource = dt;
    mydatalist.DataBind();
    sq.con.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is a question/answer site... I cannot see a question, just a set of statements.  What are you having trouble with (other than having two controls with the same ID)?

Comment: The above sample code will display one product say "Apple" and one comment say "sweet apple".What i need is multiple comment for the product "Apple".I hope its clear now.

Comment: @sum1: Yes, I can see the requirement!! But what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is How do i achieve that requirement?

Comment: @sum1: To let you know, you don't ask the requirements here. Have a look at [Hierarchical Data Binding in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478959.aspx) which will help you to start with something

Comment: @sum1: Yes, you haven't shown anything you tried!!

Comment: Add the code by which you are setting the DataList.